# h:valueChangeListener being called twice

Tags: jsp, jsf, richfaces, listener, onchange

Here is my JSP code:

```
(...)
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{MyMB.booleanValue}"
        valueChangeListener="#{MyMB.myListenerMethod}">
    <a4j:support ajaxSingle="true" event="onchange"/>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
(...)
<a4j:commandLink value="CONTINUE"
        Title="Continue" alt="Continue" action="#{MyMB.btnContinue}" />
(...)
```

The problem is: When I click on checkbox, `MyMB.myListenerMethod` is called and I change the value of `My.booleanValue` to `event.getNewValue()`.

It's working for both, check and uncheck.

But, when I click on `commandLink` to call `MyMB.btnContinue`, before this the `MyMB.myListenerMethod` is called again. Always with a false value.

What am I missing?

Comment: what is the scope of your MB. can you paste MB code. if you are always getting false value when method in commandLink executes, it means, components value has not been updated in the model. If you want the value, you can create a component binding for the component in bean and use component.getSubmittedValue() to get the value selected by user for checkBox.

Comment: The problem is: When I click on checkbox, MyMB.myListenerMethod is called and I change the value of My.booleanValue to event.getNewValue(). -------> I think you do not need to change the value explicitly in valueChangeListener in the bean. You can skip this thing in the valuchangelistener. it will be done by JSF automatically if any validation is not failed.  in <a4j:support> you are not rendering anything, what is it being used for ?